# MongoDB - How to add into object that is inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, object, mongodb-update

I am new to MongoDB and PHP and I am trying to make an API. The current problem I have is that I am not able to add an array to an object that is inside an array (of objects). I have tried a lot, but all failed.

**This is the document I have so far:**

```
_id:62307ccecabc9c2a2c4563e3
username:"NEWUser"
email:user@mail.com
password:1234
level:1
domainArray:Array
  0:Object
     domainname:"example.com"
     domainvalue:4
  1:Object
     domainname:"facebook.com"
     domainvalue:3
```

I would like to add an array after `domainvalue`, but can't seem to do that.

**My code:**

```
public function postDomain($domainData){//add user and replace it with testuser
     $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
     $collection = $collection = (new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://localhost:27017'))->mydb->users;
     $insertOneResult = $collection->updateOne(
         ["username" => "NEWUser"],
         ['$push' =>["domainArray" => $data]]
     );
}
```

**The `$data` variable:**

```
{
    "domainname":"twitter.com",
    "domainvalue":2
}
```

How would I change this code so that there is an array added after `domainvalue`?
I have tried doing things like this:

```
$insertOneResult = $collection->updateOne(
    ["username" => "NEWUser", "domainArray"],
    ['$push' => ["domainname.$.ouputArray" => array("outputArray")]]
);
```

But without any luck. Can someone please help me because I am really stuck with this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KK4NUiVlo4k)?

Comment: Yes!! It needs to be like that!

Comment: @YongShun Do you perhaps know how I would achieve that using PHP?

Comment: Not PHP developer. Guess something like this: `$insertOneResult = $collection->updateOne(
    ["username" => "NEWUser"],
    ['$set' => ["domainArray.$[].ouputArray" => array("outputArray")]]
);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new field for the nested documents in an array, you need the `$set` operator and [`$[]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) all positional operator.

```
db.collection.update({
  "username": "NEWUser"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "domainArray.$[].ouputArray": []  // Array
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KK4NUiVlo4k)

While for PHP syntax:

```
$insertOneResult = $collection->updateOne(
    ["username" => "NEWUser"],     
    ['$set' => ["domainArray.$[].ouputArray" => array("outputArray")]]
);
```